# Are IMAP email identifiers unique in PHP?

Tags: php, email, gmail, imap, gmail-imap

My goal is to be able to use a form, checkbox and submit button (delete button) to remove specific emails.

I am starting off with this connection script:

```
<?php

//Inbox - Connect;
$inbox = imap_open($folder_inbox,$username,$password) or die('Error connecting to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

//Grab Inbox Emails;
$inbox_emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');

//If there are emails;
if($inbox_emails) {

    //Output Arrays;
    $inbox_from = array();
    $inbox_subject = array();
    $inbox_date = array();
    $inbox_msg = array();

    //Put the newest emails to the top;
    rsort($inbox_emails);

    //For each email, Give it an email number;
    foreach($inbox_emails as $inbox_email_number) {

        //Get information specific to this email;
        $inbox_overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$inbox_email_number,0);

        $str_date = $inbox_overview[0]->date;
        include('../func/inbox/grab/datefix.php');

        mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

        //Add email information to the arrays;
        $inbox_read[] = $inbox_overview[0]->seen;
        $inbox_from[] = str_replace('"',"", str_replace("_"," ", mb_decode_mimeheader($inbox_overview[0]->from)));
        $inbox_subject[] = str_replace("_"," ", mb_decode_mimeheader($inbox_overview[0]->subject));
        $inbox_date[] = $str_date;
        //$inbox_msg[] = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$inbox_email_number,2);

    }

} 

//Close The Connection;
imap_close($inbox);

?>
```

I know [how to move an email to a trash folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6919603) but I am concerned that there might be a race condition between getting a set of IDs for a folder and, a few minutes later, requesting the deletion of one of those items.

For example, I have my form showing 2 email subjects, I click the checkbox related to email 1 which has the id '1', then click the delete button which submits the form. The checkbox will have the `name="1"` parameter. Now when we submit the form lets say on the submit page it uses post gets the id 1 but lets say before we loaded the PHP file I got a new email wouldn't it incorrectly delete the new email rather then the email we checked?

Comment: the function you want is  `imap_delete()`

Comment: I understand but how am I meant to delete specific emails?

Comment: by giving it the msg_number as the 2nd argument

Comment: Oh ok, But how can I get a Message Number is there a IMAP header for it?

Comment: your imap_search returns the message nummbers

Comment: Not too sure what you mean, All my imap_search is doing is grabbing the emails.

Comment: From the docs of [`imap_search()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-search.php): _Returns an array of message numbers or UIDs_. Try doing a `print_r()` on the array it returns to see what you are working with. I imagine you'd use that identifier in your checkbox `name` attribute to mark each one in your UI.

Comment: @halfer Thank you for the reply, I got this output: `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 [5] => 6 [6] => 7 [7] => 8 [8] => 9 [9] => 10 [10] => 11 [11] => 12 [12] => 13 [13] => 14 [14] => 15 )` What does this mean?

Comment: The first numbers (to the left of `=>`) are just ordinary array indexes, starting from 0. And the second numbers (to the right) are the ID of each email item. To get an email item, you'll need to use another IMAP library call, specifying this ID number.

Comment: (My earlier answer seems not to have helped, so am transferring a couple of comments here). If you question really is "how do I delete an email via IMAP", then the manual will help here - have you found the command to do this? It sounds like you have, but that it only moves the item to trash and does not delete it. Have you researched as to whether that is an intended behaviour with IMAP, or is that a Gmail design decision?

Comment: [This manual page](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-delete.php) says you need to delete (which really marks for deletion) and then expunge. Have you tried that?

Comment: Gmail is weird with deleted messages. Specifically, deleting an email removes the current label from the message. It will continue to exist in All Mail. If you want to "delete" a message you need to move it to the trash, then delete it from there.

Comment: @halfer Yes is right. You need tomove it for it to actually delete. Just to say I dont want to delete it from Trash, Just want to move it to trash. I have no idea how to do this doe. Currently changing to store to database.

Comment: Any good? http://stackoverflow.com/q/6919603

Comment: Well I mean, That answer seems fine but still doesnt answer this question, Like lets say, I have my form showing 2 email subjects, I click the checkbox related to email 1 which has the id '1', then click the delete button which submits the form. The checkbox will have the name="1" parameter. Now when we submit the form lets say on the submit page it uses post gets the id 1 but lets say before we loaded the php file I got a new email wouldnt it incorrectly delete the new email rather then the email we checked?

Comment: @ShinyMagikarp: I've not done this programmatically, but I would expect not. Wouldn't the new incoming email have a different ID? Have you tried this with some scripts and a local test IMAP server to find out?

Comment: Based on the above conversation, I've rewritten the question to be less broad, so you can get actionable answers. Do try setting up a test environment to determine if IMAP IDs are unique, but perhaps some voices of experience will chime in too.

Comment: Aha! I think [this is exactly the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4575425/472495) you are after.

Comment: I see the answer and yes its exactly what I need. Don't know if this works with Gmail's IMAP sessions, The commenter on the question shows this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-uid.php Would this one be better or should I use the Answers http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-mailboxmsginfo.php

Comment: Checked and nowhere http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-mailboxmsginfo.php Gets me any number related stuff, And in imap_uid apparently it changes on gmail when you move it to a folder which wont make a difference. But it needs a message sequence number... How do I get it?

Comment: @halfer Sorry forgot you dont get notifications.

Comment: @Halfer Okay, I got it working found out what my Sequence Number was, But may I ask, How big are UUIDS meant to be and Are they randomly generated? Why im asking is because im really unsure if my UIDS are correct, I seem to be getting 4 numbers which are just basically incremented by one each email. Is this normal?

Comment: @Halfer After I sorted them by UID in phpmyadmin it seems like a lot of mail in the same folder have the same UID. Not sure what to do now.

Comment: I don't know, as I've not used the PHP IMAP library. Perhaps you could add those questions by editing your post, and perhaps someone will expand on those points? I don't know enough about this topic to understand whether this is essentially a duplicate of the other question, or you have a different set of doubts.

Comment: @Halfer I decided to go a different route. Basically after it adds the emails to the database it will remove all emails out of gmail and into the trash using imap_mail_move but for some reason: `imap_mail_move($inbox, '*', '[Gmail]/Trash');
imap_expunge($inbox);
imap_close($inbox); ` wont work. It doesnt give any errors either... :/

Comment: 1:* Seems to work :D

Comment: Alright, if you have an answer, please add the detail below. Thanks!

Comment: Answer:

       `imap_mail_move($inbox, '1:*', '[Gmail]/Trash');
 imap_expunge($inbox);
 imap_close($inbox);`